# How do I subset/split this table bases on the values of one column in R?

Tags: r, statistics

The data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7pc11hhiwr8zzn/data.csv?dl=0 , or else as `nlschools` in the library MASS.

I'd like to split this table based on the value of nlschools$SES, having the table divide into tables where `nlschools$SES` is `<=30`, `30 < SES <= 40` and `> 40`, and with all the columns remaining.

I have tried using cut with intervals like `0:30`, but the result is very confusing and does not have the complete set of columns remaining.

I hope what I'm trying to achieve is described clear enough.

Comment: @akrun it is very basic and apparently wrong; 'sesLOW <- table(cut(nlschools$SES, 0:30))'. Your command however returns this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7n6c9sg9ca0iwi/akrun.csv?dl=0 , where each index now only has a value of either (-Inf, 30), (30,40), or (40, Inf)

Comment: Yes, my intention is to split the whole dataset, keeping all columns, and have it split into three separate datasets, e.g. using `sesLOW` will yield the complete table, but only with entries which have nlschools$SES <= 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
one<-subset(nlschools, nlschools$SES <=30)
two<-subset(nlschools, nlschools$SES >30 &  nlschools$SES<=40)
three<-subset(nlschools, nlschools$SES >40)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
indx <- with(nlschools,cut(SES, c(-Inf, 30, 40, Inf)))
lst <- split(nlschools, indx)
    
lapply(lst, head,2)
#$`(-Inf,30]`
#  lang   IQ class GS SES COMB
#1   46 15.0   180 29  23    0
#2   45 14.5   180 29  10    0

#$`(30,40]`
#  lang   IQ class GS SES COMB
#37   39 11.0  1082 25  33    1
#39   43 10.5  1280 31  33    1

#$`(40, Inf]`
#  lang IQ class GS SES COMB
#49   31  9  1280 31  50    1
#71   45 15  1880 28  50    0
```

If you need it as separate datasets:

```
list2env(setNames(lst, c("sesLOW", "sesMED", "sesHIGH")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>


head(sesLOW,3)
#  lang   IQ class GS SES COMB.
#1   46 15.0   180 29  23    0
#2   45 14.5   180 29  10    0
#3   33  9.5   180 29  15    0
```

Checking the results with @Ujjwal's post

```
identical(sesLOW, one)
#[1] TRUE

identical(sesMED, two)
#[1] TRUE

identical(sesHIGH, three)
#[1] TRUE
```

However, it would be much easier to do all the analysis/calculations within the list rather than as separate datasets.  Even you can save the list elements separately using `lapply` and `write.table/write.csv` etc

#### Update

If you want to create a new column within the `list`

```
names(lst) <- c("low","med", "high")#no need to rename the list elements though. You can directly use it as a vector in the `Map`
lst2 <- Map(function(x, y) {x[,"SEScat"] <- y;x }, lst, names(lst))
lapply(lst2, head,2)
#$low
#  lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
#1   46 15.0   180 29  23    0    low
#2   45 14.5   180 29  10    0    low

#$med
#  lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
#37   39 11.0  1082 25  33    1    med
#39   43 10.5  1280 31  33    1    med

#$high
#  lang IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
#49   31  9  1280 31  50    1   high
#71   45 15  1880 28  50    0   high
```

Comment: Thank you. I can understand that it's easier to do analysis within the list. For example, if I wish to create an extra column with low, med, high obeying the previous tresholds (<= 30, etc), how would I do that? Something like `nlschools$SEScat <- (pseudo: low if SES <=30, med if 30 < SES <=40, high if SES > 40)`?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment to @akrun, try:

```
> ddf$SEScat = with(ddf, ifelse(SES<=30,'low', ifelse(SES<=40, 'med', 'high')))
> ll = split(ddf, ddf$SEScat)

> head(ll[[1]])
      X lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
49   49   31  9.0  1280 31  50    1   high
71   71   45 15.0  1880 28  50    0   high
82   82   47 12.0  1880 28  50    0   high
85   85   33 13.0  1880 28  50    0   high
90   90   31 10.5  1880 28  50    0   high
145 145   50 13.5  2680 21  45    0   high
> head(ll[[2]])
  X lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
1 1   46 15.0   180 29  23    0    low
2 2   45 14.5   180 29  10    0    low
3 3   33  9.5   180 29  15    0    low
4 4   46 11.0   180 29  23    0    low
5 5   20  8.0   180 29  10    0    low
6 6   30  9.5   180 29  10    0    low
> head(ll[[3]])
    X lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
37 37   39 11.0  1082 25  33    1    med
39 39   43 10.5  1280 31  33    1    med
40 40   25  8.5  1280 31  33    1    med
42 42   41 11.0  1280 31  37    1    med
45 45   21  9.5  1280 31  40    1    med
52 52   29  8.5  1280 31  40    1    med
```