# How do I append an extra column to my dataset, and give them string values, in R?

Tags: r, statistics, dataset

Dataset can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7pc11hhiwr8zzn/data.csv?dl=0 or as "nlschools" in the MASS library.

In this dataset, I'd like to add an extra column called `SEScat`, which indexes the values in the SES column as either low (<=30), med (30 < SES <=40), or high (>40). In my imagination, the command could look someting like this:
`> nlschools$SEScat <- (pseudo: low if SES <=30, med if 30 < SES <=40, high if SES > 40)`, but I have not been able to find the fitting syntax and the documentation seems to rely on much more background knowledge than I have.

Before this will work however, I have to make an extra column. Using `names(nlschools) <- c("lang","IQ","class","GS","SES","COMB","SEScat")` does not work, because the name attribute does not have sufficient length. I'm not sure how to increase this.

This question has came up from a previous question I asked, but I thought it might be handy for other users to have it as a separate question. I hope that is okay.

Comment: `nlschools <- within(nlschools,{ SEScat <- ifelse(SES<=30,"low",ifelse(SES<=40,"med","high")) })`

Comment: @Thomas The first part seems to be fixed from your earlier post?  If you already received the answer, I don't understand the need for asking it as separate question.

Comment: This link will take you there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235205/how-do-i-subset-split-this-table-bases-on-the-values-of-one-column-in-r/26236620#26236620

Comment: My bad, I did not notice I received another answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The straight way of doing this is by looping through each individual value in the SES column (using the for loop) and testing if each value fits your categories (low,mid and high). You do that by using the if and else statement. Then write the result to the current row of a newly created column a$SEScat.

```
# load data
a <-read.csv('data.csv')

# loop through individual SES values
for (i in a$SES)
{
  # check for low 
  if (i <= 30)
  {

  # write to new column
  a$SEScat = 'low'

  # check for mid
  } else if (i > 30 && i <= 40)
  {

  # write to new column
  a$SEScat = 'mid'

  # check for high
  } else 
  {

  # write to new column
  a$SEScat = 'high'
}
}

# display data frame
View(a)
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice!

Comment: Apologies for no explanation. Load in your data set then loop through the values in the SES column using a for loop while testing if each individual value is less than 30, between 30 and 40 or greater than 40. If a condition is met it is written to a new row in the created column a$SEScat.

Comment: Edit your answer with the text you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
> ddf$SEScat = with(ddf, ifelse(SES<=30,'low', ifelse(SES<=40, 'med', 'high')))
> head(ddf)
  X lang   IQ class GS SES COMB SEScat
1 1   46 15.0   180 29  23    0    low
2 2   45 14.5   180 29  10    0    low
3 3   33  9.5   180 29  15    0    low
4 4   46 11.0   180 29  23    0    low
5 5   20  8.0   180 29  10    0    low
6 6   30  9.5   180 29  10    0    low
>
```

Can be split as shown in: [How do I subset/split this table bases on the values of one column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235205/how-do-i-subset-split-this-table-bases-on-the-values-of-one-column-in-r/26236620#26236620)